# Simulate a mouse click

Tags: android, webview

I've a bit strange and rare task: I want to simulate mouse click on `WebView`.

If my understanding correct, I should create `MotionEvent` instance and pass it to the `dispatchGenericMotionEvent` method.

I tried this, it doesn't work:

```
      float x = 100;
      float y = 100;
      long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
      long downTime = eventTime;

      // Press button
      MotionEvent motionEvent = getMotionEvent(x, y, MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_EXIT, eventTime, downTime, MotionEvent.BUTTON_PRIMARY);
      webView.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(motionEvent);

      eventTime += 100;
      downTime += 100;

      // Release button
      MotionEvent motionEvent1 = getMotionEvent(x, y, MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_ENTER, eventTime, downTime, 0);
      webView.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(motionEvent1);


   /**
    * Create MotionEvent instance
    */
   private MotionEvent getMotionEvent(float x, float y, int action, long eventTime,
                                      long downTime, int buttonState) {

      MotionEvent.PointerCoords pointerCoords = new MotionEvent.PointerCoords();
      pointerCoords.x = x;
      pointerCoords.y = y;
      MotionEvent.PointerCoords[] pointerCoordsArr = {pointerCoords};

      MotionEvent.PointerProperties pointerProperties = new MotionEvent.PointerProperties();
      pointerProperties.toolType = MotionEvent.TOOL_TYPE_MOUSE;
      pointerProperties.id = 0;
      MotionEvent.PointerProperties[] pointerPropertiesArr = {pointerProperties};

      int deviceId = 1;
      int pointerCount = 1;
      int metaState = 0;
      float xPrecision = 0;
      float yPrecision = 0;
      int edgeFlags = 0;
      int flags = 0;

      return MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, action, pointerCount, pointerPropertiesArr,
              pointerCoordsArr, metaState, buttonState, xPrecision, yPrecision, deviceId,
              edgeFlags, InputDevice.SOURCE_MOUSE, flags);

   }
```

At the same time, the `WebView` is able to handle mouse movement emulation:

```
  long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
  long downTime = eventTime;

  // go to 100, 100
  MotionEvent motionEvent = getMotionEvent(100, 100, MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_MOVE, eventTime, downTime, 0);
  webView.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(motionEvent);

  eventTime += 100;
  downTime += 100;

  // go to 101, 101
  MotionEvent motionEvent1 = getMotionEvent(101, 101, MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_MOVE, eventTime, downTime, 0);
  webView.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(motionEvent1);
```

Why doesn't the click emulation works? What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this issue? I have tried the same approach and did not work for me either.

Comment: For me, creating this sequence of events (with proper values) works for clicks: ACTION_DOWN --> ACTION_MOVE --> ACTION_UP